# How to call a method with instance using Expression

Tags: c#

For example I have some class with some property:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public Version Version { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a list of this type with sample data:

```
var list = new List<SomeClass>();

for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    list.Add(new SomeClass
    {
        Version = new Version(i, i / 2, i / 3, i / 4),
    });
}
```

I want to write method that filters by version using Version.Equals method:

```
var filterValue = new Version(12, 6, 4, 3);

var modelType = typeof(SomeClass);
var propertyType = typeof(Version);
var arg = Expression.Parameter(modelType, "x");
var property = Expression.Property(arg, "Version");
var value = Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(filterValue), propertyType);
var versionEqualsMethod = typeof(Version).GetMethod("Equals", new[] { typeof(Version) });

/////////
Expression inst = null; // <-- ???
/////////

var expr = Expression.Call(inst, versionEqualsMethod, property, value);

var delegateType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(modelType, typeof(bool));
var delegateValue = Expression.Lambda(delegateType, expr, arg).Compile();

var genericMethod =
    typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods()
        .First(
            method =>
                method.Name == "Where" && method.IsGenericMethodDefinition
                && method.GetGenericArguments().Length == 1 && method.GetParameters().Length == 2)
        .MakeGenericMethod(modelType);

var result = genericMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { list, delegateValue });
```

What do I use as instance in Expression.Call?

**UPDATE**

Solution is:

```
var expr = Expression.Call(property, versionEqualsMethod, value);
```

Comment: Do you want to test or learn Expression? or your example is your case?

Comment: I want to write an extension for filtering of IEnumerable<T>. It just a case of using Expression.Call with instance.

Comment: Why not use reflection? Would be much easier. See my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You normally would do:

```
var filterValue = new Version(12, 6, 4, 3);

var modelType = typeof(SomeClass);
var propertyType = typeof(Version);
var arg = Expression.Parameter(modelType, "x");
var property = Expression.Property(arg, "Version");

// Changes from here onward
var value = Expression.Constant(filterValue);
var versionEqualsMethod = typeof(Version).GetMethod("Equals", new[] { typeof(Version) });
var expr = Expression.Call(property, versionEqualsMethod, value);
```

Because the `Equals` would be used like:

```
model.Version.Equals(filterValue);
```

I'm **not** handling the `model.Version == null` case!

Note that you don't need the `Expression.Convert`.

And what you are doing is ok if the "containing method" (the method where you'll put this code) is non-generic, but normally it would be a generic method, that has as the generic parameter the `modelType`, so the last part of the code would be different (starting from `var delegateType =`), because you could use the `TModelType` generic type directly.

Comment: I need Expression.Convert for Nullable<T> properties. When I use the property as instance I get following exception: Incorrect number of arguments supplied for call to method 'Boolean Equals(System.Version)'

Comment: @Vitone The case you showed is for `Version`, that is a `class`, that can't be a `Nullable<>`... But if you want to use it with nullable types, I see its use.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing out on something, but wouldn't this work:

```
var results = list.Where(sc => sc.Version == filterVersion);
```

Comment: It's just an example. I want to call different methods dynamically using Expression.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to accomplish is much easier to do with reflection. Check [this running online example](http://rextester.com/ZSLO47636). (If I understand you correctly that is... It would be helpful, if you could provide the signature of the function you are trying to write.)

**Implementation**

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Filter<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, string propertyName, object filterValue)
    {
        var elementType = typeof (T);
        var property = elementType.GetProperty(propertyName);

        return enumerable.Where(element =>
        {
            var propertyValue = property.GetMethod.Invoke(element, new object[] {});
            return propertyValue.Equals(filterValue);
        });
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var list = new List<SomeClass>();

for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    list.Add(new SomeClass {Version = new Version(i, i/2, i/3, i/4)});
}

var filteredList = list.Filter("Version", new Version(12, 6, 4, 3));

Console.WriteLine(filteredList.Single().Version);
```

Comment: Yes, it's easier but my approach is more functional. For example, your filter does not work in this case: var filteredList = list.Filter("Version.Major", 12) while my filter works. And I can add as many filters as I want.

Comment: @Vitone, now I'm curious. Can you please update your question or the accepted answer with your solution? (It sounds like you already found the solution.) What I'm seeing now looks just horrible in terms of usability. What is your function signature? Does it take an `Expression` object and an `object` as filter value? I bet my ten fingers it's still easier to parse a string like `Version.Major` and use reflection to get the property value.